# Midlet must not closed even press cut button of device

Tags: java, java-me, midp

I am working in J2ME. I want that my MIDlet must run for infinite time. It must not close even I press any of key from my device.

Please help me what should I do for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a Nokia handset you can add Nokia-MIDlet-No-Exit: true in Jad file: http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-C5D3E0F5-72B9-4EE7-8BA7-20DE4A538FB8.html

This other question is also about this [minimizing a mobile application on exit button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869653/minimizing-a-mobile-application-on-exit-button-press)

Comment: can I use Nokia-MIDlet-No-Exit: true in Jad file even i did not sign my MIDlet ? I am using Nokia device and writing above code which is suggested by you but it still now working.

Comment: Are you sore your device supports this key? Nokia site says that this is available since Symbian edition "S60 3rd Edition FP 2".

Comment: The documentation says that Nokia-MIDlet-No-Exit is available for All domains, so you do not need to sign your MIDlet. Maybe the issue is wether the key is found: only in Jad; only in Jar/manifets; both. What have yout tried?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that any device can close any MIDlet it runs. This can be done by the platform and you can't do anything about it in J2ME. The only solution is to make your custom firmware (or OS) by patching it.

Answer (score -1):

It should not be `Nokia-MIDlet-No-Exit:true` but it should be
`Nokia-MIDlet-no-exit: true`
but for using this, you will first break Nokia security firewall by hacking your s40 device.