# Start MIDlet automatically when device reboots?

Tags: java-me, nokia, midp, s60

I am working in J2ME. I want that my application must be **automatically started when my device reboots**.

I have made **Nokia-MIDlet-auto-start: yes** entry in my JAD file as suggested in

http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-C22F1733-6877-42EC-A610-40F9E592C92D.html

The MIDlet is currently unsigned, and I am using Nokia handsets for testing (the Nokia S60 in particular).Regardless off the steps I took, as mentioned above,  when I reboot my device the app does not start automatically.

Please suggest me what should I do to automatically restart my MIDLet on device boot. Thanks.

Comment: the WTK won't notice the entry you added, since as explained in answers to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10433330/839601) this will work only on _Nokia handsets_. Also, as explained in these answers, there is no generic way way to achieve stuff like that in MIDP 2

Comment: @gnat I am using in Nokia Handsets also. I installed my application in Nokia S60. But when i reboot my device then this is not starting automatically.

Comment: why you wrote _I am using WTK_ then?

Comment: @gnat sir, I did not singed my MIDLet. can I use 

Nokia-MIDlet-auto-start: yes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your link:

"You can set MIDlets running in the manufacturer or operator domain to start automatically on device boot"

This means that it will only work if Nokia or the handset operator trusts the certificate you use to sign your MIDlet.

The property will not work on unsigned MIDlets.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710423/privileged-operations-in-netbeans-mobility) contains a bit more information about domains.